# How to declare settings in an app that later can be generally overriden?

Tags: django

I am coding a reusable django-app and I'd like to set some settings, say in a settings.py file inside the app folder, which later can be overriden by other developer on their settings.py file. Is there a particular way, python-zen-way to achieve this rather than the described above?

For instance in my settings.py the pagiation elements would be...

```
default_pagination_elements = 9
```

But I'd like the user of the app to be able to override that in their settings.py...

Which is the best way to achieve this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to allow for a user to provide their own value for a setting is to use `getattr` and provide a default value

```
from django.conf import settings
my_setting = getattr(settings, 'MY_SETTING', 'default')
```

This way if the user has not defined the setting you will still get the default value

For your case:

```
default_pagination_elements = getattr(settings, 'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_ELEMENTS', 9)
```